# what is the CommandUIDefinition location for wiki page

Tags: ribbon

I am trying to add custom ribbon button to the share point menu for wiki library under manage group. I am able to see the ribbon button on "view all pages" section of wiki library.But when I open the individual wiki page I did not find custom ribbon button.

code

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Manage.Controls._children">
```

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've got this, but just to be sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx

Looks like you're targeting the list's ribbon, rather than the individual pages.

Try targetting the wike page template content type via RegistrationType and RegistrationId attributes in CustomAction.

Type should be "ListItem".

Content Type GUID (i.e ID) should be 0x01010800942F84D3E420D748BA4C54F67124A8F7

But you can find it in the Content Type's Settings page's url.